# Do I need article in front of the word "hints"

Tags: articles

"And you can see hints of fall with the golden yellow leaves on the tree tops"
Do I need article "the" in front of the word hints, and if I don't why not? :)

Also, in the sentence : I should visit places with the most beautiful views. 
Does article go in front of the word places or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both your sentences are correct as they stand, and would be awkward if you added an article.

Comment: @DanBron I see nothing 'awkward' about them at all. *I see hints of autumn...* versus *I see the hints of autumn*, are are clearly different in meaning but so are *persons were seen entering the building* versus *the persons were seen entering the building*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't want an article there. "Hints of fall" conforms to a poetic formula, like "memories of Spring", "legends of the fall", "premonitions of mortality".

Answer (score 0):

Both of your sentences are grammatically correct without `the`, and would be equally correct with `the`.

If you *had* to come up with a [rule regarding article use](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/), it would be that `the` is used when referring to a specific thing or group of things, and not used when the thing is more general. `The` refers to "this particular group of hints" or "this particular group of places".

(Due to that, I think the second sentence should have a `the`, or at least would sound better with, because it's specific places with a specific characteristic.)

But, practically speaking, it's a small difference. The rule isn't a hard and fast one in regular English, and I don't think using one or the other (in your case) will make things particularly awkward.